# Allow posting of recommendations on your CV

Tags: feature-request

1. User can send any number of invitations to write a recommendation via email

   - Encoded link to write recommendation
   - Recommender can edit / preview / leave & resume / a recommendation
   - User approves recommendation and is posted to CV

Comment: There would need to be some kind of identity verification, otherwise you could just write your own recommendations.  On LinkedIn you can only be recommended by other people with a LinkedIn profile.

Answer (score 1):

SO is not a social networking site, sadly.  You'd have to get recommendations from your peers (ie, other SO users) but the site doesn't really connect people well enough to allow for this.  Other verification systems are doomed to be too much work, or not work at all.

I'd like to see this done, I just don't see how it can be done well.

But I believe that it doesn't matter so much - potential employers, if they aren't impressed with your resume, aren't going to be impressed with your recommendations.  They will ask for recommendations during the interview process.

Keep in mind that reputation, though poor, is merit given by one's peers, and thus is a recommendation as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Careers is slowly turning into linkedin (at least if all feature-requests are implemented)

I'm not saying it's wrong or right though, I kinda like this suggestion

Comment: I wonder if the SO team wouldn't be better off just integrating LinkedIn into SOC... Synchronization of public resumes has also been requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would like this, or the ability for myself to upload letters of recommendation that I have from colleagues